# Automatizar tabla dinámica con VBA utilizando función IMPORTARDATOSDINAMICOS

Tags: excel, vba

Cordial saludo equipo espero que se encuentren bien, necesito pedirles el favor con lo siguiente:

Tengo la siguiente funcion en  Excel , referente a ImportarDatosDinamicos de  tablas dinámicas,
=+IMPORTARDATOSDINAMICOS("[Measures].[Suma de # Eliminaciones]";$A$6)

Pero en la empresa en que estoy trabajando me solicitan automatizar dicho proceso haciendo uso
del lenguaje de programacion VBA, para ello hago uso del siguiente código en VBA:

Set pt = Sheet1.PivotTables("AAAA")
Hoja4.Cells(i1, j1) = pt.GetPivotData("[Measures].Hoja4.Cells(i1-4, j1)", A6).Value

En donde AAAA, hace referencia al nombre que se le da a la tabla dinámica pero desafortunadamente
no veo en que parte aparece el nombre de la tabla dinámica dentro del Excel.

agradezco su colaboracion con este código o con otro que ustedes tengan para implementar datos
dinámicos en Excel con el lenguaje VBA.

Muchas gracias anticipadas.

Comment: *no veo en que parte aparece el nombre de la tabla dinámica dentro del Excel* En la cinta de opciones, grupo **analizar tabla dinámica**, a la izquierda del todo

Comment: El inconveniente es ese, que no veo dentro de la hoja de trabajo, en donde esta el atributo Measures

Comment: Si tienes la tabla dinámica creada, si seleccionas cualquier celda de la tabla dinámica, tienes acceso a los campos/atributos. En caso de que no se te vean, en la cinta de opciones, grupo analizar tabla dinámica, a la derecha del todo hay un comando que pone **lista de campos**. Y con eso te sale el configurador donde puedes ver todos los atributos.